# Rails Sort Results based on an association to a child model's method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I've got an Event model. and this Event model has_one Address model.  A User model also has_one Address model.  I want to get a list of all events in the future, but sorted based on distance between the events address and the users address.  This 'distance' is a method on my address model.  how can i write the rails query with active record? I've tried many variations of the following but nothing seems to work.

```
Event.where('end_time > ?', Time.now).includes(Address).order(address.distance_from(User.find(3).primary_address))
```

i always get this error: NameError: undefined local variable or method `address' for main:Object

definitions of Event and User:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
   # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable

   has_many :addresses
   belongs_to :primary_address, :class_name => "Address"


class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend TimeFromPieces

  attr_accessor :start_date_string

  belongs_to :address
  delegate :timezone, to: :address
```

here is my address model:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :events

  validates_presence_of :name, :address1, :city, :state, :zip

  geocoded_by :address_as_string do |obj, results|
    Rails.logger.debug { "results: #{results}" }
    obj.lat = results.first.coordinates[0]
    obj.lng = results.first.coordinates[1]
    Rails.logger.debug { "Neighborhoods: #{results.first.address_components_of_type(:neighborhood)}" }
    neighborhoods = results.first.address_components_of_type(:neighborhood)
    if neighborhoods.count > 1
      obj.neighborhood = neighborhoods.first["long_name"]
    end
  end

  after_validation :geocode, :if => :address1_changed?
  after_validation :time_zone_for_address, :if => :address1_changed?

  before_save :set_primary_if_only_address_for_user
  before_save :normalize_fields

  scope :near, ->(lat, lng, distance_in_meters = 2000) {
    where(%{
      ST_Dwithin(
        ST_GeographyFromText(
          'SRID=4326;POINT(' || addresses.lng || ' ' || addresses.lat || ')'
        ),
        ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(%f %f)'),
        %d
      )
      } % [lng, lat, distance_in_meters])
  }

  def self.distance(address1, address2)
    query = %{ SELECT
      ST_Distance(
        ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(%f %f)'),
        ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(%f %f)')
      )
    } % [address1.lng, address1.lat, address2.lng, address2.lat]

    meters = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query).values.first.first.to_i
    meters/1609.34
  end

  def distance_from(address)
    Address.distance(self, address)
  end
end
```

Comment: what is the gem that provides `geocoded_by` ?

Comment: One thing to notice here is that you are getting fooled by "rails magic." If you look closely at this part of your code: .order(address.distance_from(User.find(3).primary_address)) you will see where your error is coming from.  I am guessing that the variable address is not in scope.

Comment: You also can't pass ruby code into the ActiveRecord method chain like you are doing. That might require the adapter to execute ruby as part of a SQL query. Which would be super cool!  As @MohammadAbuShady is guiding you here, an gem that extends AR with geo abilities is the way to go here.

Comment: thanks @digidigo for pointing out the SQL vs RUBY conflict. I'll try the solution outlined by MohammadAbuShady

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a ruby geocoder, you could use a gem like [geokit-rails](https://github.com/geokit/geokit-rails), which provides geocoding abilities to active record, it gives you nice methods that allow you to query by distance directly to the database, so you don't need to fetch all objects to calculate their distance

You could say that address is a mappable object, and point the lat and lng fields ( if they aren't using the default names used by the gem )

```
class Address
  acts_as_mappable
end
```

Then you could say that an event is also mappable through the address object attached to it

```
class Event
  acts_as_mappable through: :address
end
```

The query would look something like this

```
Event.where('end_time < ?', Time.now).by_distance(origin: address)
```